# Orbitcontrols - how to load last view position and rotation

Tags: three.js

how would I be able to save and load the last view position and rotation when using the orbitalcontrols? When my 3D page is refreshed, I want to load the page at the last view instead of going back to the default position, zoom, and rotation. I am using three.js version 71. Thanks,

Jim

Comment: I had faced the same problem. I updatet orbit controls class and returned and stored pan angles. But you will have next problem after that, to set when user is left your page and define the time when you have to store last camera coords. I stopped in this phase to solving it and left camera in default position on start.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const loadControls = (controls) => {
  const stateJSON = localStorage.getItem(`orbitControls`);

  if (stateJSON) {
    const { target0, position0, zoom0 } = JSON.parse(stateJSON);
    controls.target0.copy(target0);
    controls.position0.copy(position0);
    controls.zoom0 = zoom0;
    controls.reset();
  }
};

const saveControls = (controls) => {
  controls.saveState();
  const { target0, position0, zoom0 } = controls;
  const state = { target0, position0, zoom0 };
  localStorage.setItem(`orbitControls`, JSON.stringify(state));
};

const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

document.addEventListener(`visibilitychange`, () => {
  saveControls(controls);
});
```

Comment: you can also use `const { target, position, zoom } = controls;` without using `controls.saveState()` which gives the same result without having to save the controls state internally